# Show the attribute of one model on the show page of another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I have the following def in the client model:

```
def cli_full_name
  [f_name, mi, l_name].join(' ')
end
```

I would like cli_full_name to display in the contract show page. Here is my app/views/contracts/show.html.haml page:

```
- provide(:title, @contract.authnum)
%h3
  = @contract.authnum
  %span1
    = @client.cli_full_name
```

I get an error, "undefined method" cli_full_name.

The association is that contract has a *has_many :clients :through => :clientlines*

So I added a nested route to my routes file thinking that this would get things to work as follows:

```
 resources :contracts do
   resources :clients
 end
```

No luck.

Can someone please help me understand how to get the cli_full_name to display on the contract show page?

Thanks.

**Update**

It works if you run over to the client show page but I want it on the contract show page:)

Even if I change my nested routes to the format proposed by Jamis Buck:

```
http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources
```

I still cannot get cli_full_name to display on the contract show page.
Maybe I do not understand nested attributes and nested routes?

Help?

Comment: A quick note: it really helps to follow Rails conventions for naming things.  Instead of `cli_full_name`, just `full_name` is better since it will always be scoped by Client.  f_name, mi and l_name could be spelled out (e.g. first_name, initial, last_name) ... and what the heck, make a full_name method in your client model that builds a full name from the components you have!  Rails is all about following conventions to make everything easier.

Comment: Thnaks @tharrison ... will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your model specifies that a contract has many clients you need to access them like this

```
@contract.clients
```

and then loop through them similar to

```
- @contract.clients.each do |client|
  = client.cli_full_name
```

Comment: Thanks NullRef .... do I add the above code to my contracts show page? If so, it returns "undefined method" clients for nilNilClass

Comment: try again. I had a typo. `@contract` not `@contracts`. Sorry

Comment: Thanks again... I had contracts instead of contract.